# Dark mode settings are missing in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

The 2 usual places for dark mode settings aren't available in my outlook install. Usually there's the option under File->Options->General->Personalize, or found in File->Office Account but neither location has the option.

The sun/moon icon in emails is also missing to change the background of the message, but from what I remember that only was useable with dark mode enabled. (Theme set to black)

Is there another option anywhere to enable this?

Comment: At this point, most Microsoft Apps use the Windows System Settings for Dark Mode. There are deficiencies to this but no Microsoft solutions at this point (some solutions appearing in Windows 11 Insider).

Comment: So many things have broken due to moving to Windows 11 so far.. I guess I'll just add this to the list. Thanks John.

Comment: I don't think many things have broken. I have been using Windows 11 Pro for 18 months. But Microsoft tried to implement Dark mode by simple settings that did not work properly.

Comment: "So many things have broken due to moving to Windows 11 so far" - Migration to Windows 11 would not change what options are available within Outlook.  You failed to indicate what version of Outlook and it's build number.

Answer (score 0):

It is clarified in [this official Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/682178/office-2019-pro-plus-dark-mode.html) that:

> “Dark Reading Mode is available for Office 365 subscribers and non-volume licensing Office 2019 customers currently, it means these users can try this feature on Word, OneNote 2016, Outlook. (Please note, this feature is not available for all Office apps, such as Excel, PowerPoint.)”